# 5V DC 500 mA adapter run 100 feet to web cam

Tags: power-supply, power, usb-device

I am using a GUCE51 USB extender 100 feet from my computer to power a web cam. The extender uses a 5V DC 500 mA power supply.

Option 1: Plug the power supply into the 110V AC on the inside and run 5V DC out to the extender.

Option 2: Run 100V AC to the power supply at the extender.

With Option 1, if I use good copper wire will I have enough power at the end of the run to power the extender?

- [Extender](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUCE51/)
- [Logitech Webcam C930e Web Cam](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/39606/section/troubleshoot/crid/405/lt_product_id/10715/tabs/1,3,2,4,5/cl/us,en)

Comment: "Good copper" is audiofool talk. Resistance and ampacity are primarily governed by gauge once purity breaks 90%.

Comment: According to the link you provided for the extender, the answer is "Option 3 - neither". The link provides no hint that an external power supply is either needed or provided. Not only that, the unit you specify is a USB1.0 /1.1. I suspect that you mean the GUCE62.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing what gauge wire you will use, I guessed 18AWG. At 100 ft (200 round trip), a 5V source voltage at 500mA will result in a ~13% Voltage drop at the far end. That is outside of the normal USB spec of ±5%, which is 4.75V to 5.25V to be in spec. It might work, it might not. **You can either increase the source voltage, or increase the cable size (16AWG results in a 8% drop instead).**

Additionally, as the current pulled increases, the voltage will drop more. V = IR after all, with R being the resistance of the cable (normally stated per foot). If the extender + Web cam actually pulls more than 500mA, this will change. If they pull less, the Voltage at the far end will be higher as well.

[image]